# Remote Desktop Connection Only Works One Way

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I can't get my desktop to connect to my laptop through remote desktop connection. Unfortunately I can only get my laptop to connect to my desktop (quite useless).

Desktop:
Windows 7 Ultimate 64 Bit SP1
Windows firewall is off for all 3 profiles (domain / private / public)
Remote desktop connection is installed and set to allow all connections

Under running services is:

```
Running Remote Desktop Configuration
Running Remote Desktop Services
Running Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector
Running Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
Stopped Remote Access Auto Connection Manager
Stopped Remote Access Connection Manager
Stopped Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator
Stopped Remote Registry
Stopped Routing and Remote Access
Stopped Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)
```

Laptop:
Windows 7 Home Premium 64 Bit SP1
Windows firewall is off for all3 profiles (domain / private / public)
Remote desktop connection is installed and set to 'Allow Remote Assistance connections to this computer'

Under running services is:

```
 Running       Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
 Stopped       Remote Access Auto Connection Manager
 Stopped       Remote Access Connection Manager
 Stopped       Remote Desktop Configuration
 Stopped       Remote Desktop Services
 Stopped       Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator
 Stopped       Remote Registry
 Stopped       Routing and Remote Access
 Stopped       Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)
```

It should be noted that the Laptop that I'm trying to connect to is an Alienware and might be running some wonky Dell settings. Also, the settings are slightly different for remote desktop connection as it's a Home edition of Windows and not Ultimate like my desktop.

Finally, both computers are on the same Homegroup so that RDC can be accessed by one click through the network section of Windows. They're also on the same workgroup, MSHOME, just to see if that helps.

Comment: I believe that is a limitation of windows home premium. You would have to upgrade to at least windows professional. Or you could use something like VNC.

Comment: You are completely correct Phillip:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/does-windows-7-home-premium-support-remote-desktop/0cb69a49-868b-47e0-a760-1a16567413bc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 Home Premium does not support RDC server:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/does-windows-7-home-premium-support-remote-desktop/0cb69a49-868b-47e0-a760-1a16567413bc